# What's the benefit of `BelongsTo` relation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

What's the benefit of defining [BelongsTo](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasMany-relation.html) relation?

When I defined `HasMany` relation I could execute all my queries without missing anyone (I prefer to give me an example in case you find it's important to use `BelongsTo` relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is being able to flip the "base" and "child" in of the relation. LoopBack 4 relation filters are akin to an SQL LEFT JOIN, meaning that the filter must be scoped from the base model.

From the ["Filtering by parent model" docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html#filtering-by-parent-model):

> Where filters such as those used by model queries (`create()`, `find()`, `replaceById()`, and so on) cannot be used to filter a model by the value of its parent model. See its [GitHub issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4299).

For example, we may have many Orders made by a Customer:

```js
@hasMany(() => Order)
orders?: Order[];
```

This relation enables querying for "orders made by a customer" or "orders made by a list of filtered customers", but not the other way around; "the customer that made that order" or "the customers that made a list of filtered orders".

A [Belongs To](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html) relation solves this by creating a key on the Order that references a Customer:

```js
@belongsTo(() => Customer)
customerId: number;
```

This means that we can now query "which customer made that order" or "which customers made the filtered list of orders".

---

Another important factor is that a Has Many relation can't be made into a Strong Relation as ANSI SQL does not have a method of representing such relations. From [the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html#weak-vs-strong-relations):

> LoopBack 4 implements weak relations with `@belongsTo()`, `@hasMany()`, `@hasOne()`, etc. This means the constraints are enforced by LoopBack 4 itself, not the underlying database engine. *This is useful for integrating cross-database relations, thereby allowing LoopBack 4 applications to partially take the role of a data lake.*
>
> However, this means that invalid data could be keyed in outside of the LoopBack 4 application. To resolve this issue, some LoopBack 4 connectors (such as [PostgreSQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/PostgreSQL-connector.html#auto-migrateauto-update-models-with-foreign-keys) and [MySQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MySQL-connector.html#auto-migrateauto-update-models-with-foreign-keys)) allow defining a [foreign key constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) through the `@model()` decorator. Please consult the respective connector documentation to check for compatibility.

Emphasis in italics is mine on why these restrictions apply.